# Creating responsive banner of size 100% x 660 px in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create the responsive banner whose full screen size is 100% x 600px.

Here is my code,

```html
<style>
  /* default height */
  
  #ad {
    height: 660px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (height:90px) {
    /* 90 pixels high */
    #ad {
      height: 690px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (height:125px) {
    /* 125 pixels high */
    #ad {
      height: 125px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .kk {
    background-image: url(/product/ProductDevelopmentBanner.jpg?expires=31536000) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>

<section id="ad" class="kk" style="height : 660px; width: 100%">
  //in section class kk shows the banner
</section>
```

Now, this code is working fine in full screen of computer but this banner is not showing properly in mobile, tablet or other gadgets.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to reduce the height of the banner on the small screens, which have a lower width. You can try this to reduce the height on tablets and smartphones:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   #ad {
      height: 125px;
   }
}
```

By the way "@media only screen and" applies only to desktop screens. i am not sure, if that is what you wanted.